# Rails_admin new model configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, rails-admin

I just installed Rails Admin, and I want to have a model called "Business". Through Rails Admin, I want to be able to create new businesses, edit them, etc. I've written the code for the model already, but I don't know how to use the rails_admin.rb file to configure the model. Here's what I have so far.

Business.rb

```
class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
  #attr_accessible :title, :body

  attr_accessible :name, :website, :phone, :manager, :email, :type, :mobile,
  :foursquare, :facebook, :yelp, :google

  validates_presence_of :name, :website, :phone, :manager, :email, :type, :mobile,
  :foursquare, :facebook, :yelp, :google

  def type_enum
    ['Agencies', 'Automotive', 'Contractor', 'Country Club', 'Entertainment',
    'Restaurant and Bar', 'Funeral', 'Furniture', 'Healthcare', 'Laundry', 'Legal',
    'Office', 'Other', 'Personal Trainer', 'Real Estate', 'Religious', 'Retail',
    'Salon', 'Wedding Hall']
  end

  def mobile_enum
    ['Yes', 'No']
  end

  def foursquare_enum
    ['Yes', 'No']
  end

  def facebook_enum
    ['Yes', 'No']
  end

  def yelp_enum
    ['Yes', 'No']
  end

  def google_enum
    ['Yes', 'No']
  end
end
```

What should I include in my rails_admin.rb? Ideally I want to have text fields to enter data for all the fields, except for the ones for which I created 'enum' methods - these should be dropdown menus. I'm new to Rails Admin, and relatively new to rails so I appreciate your help greatly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your configuration will look something like this:

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.model Business do
    list do
      field :name
      field :website
    end
    show do
      # e.g. include_all_fields
    end
    edit do
      # e.g. include_all_fields
      # exclude_fields :website
    end
  end
end
```

You can read additional field configuration [at the RailsAdmin field configuration wiki page](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Railsadmin-DSL).